# How can such code return such mess?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, normalization

So for more than 10000 openCV images I want to perform something like

```
            int maxVal;
            int minVal;
            int wh = w*h;
            int values[1000];
            for(x=0;x<w;x++){
                for(y=0;y<h;y++){
                    double RealColor = cvGetReal2D(source, y, x);
                    values[x*h + y] = RealColor; 
                }
            }
            minVal = *min_element(values,(values+wh));
            maxVal = *max_element(values,(values+wh));
            float dif = maxVal - minVal;
            float fminVal;
            fminVal = minVal;
            for(x=0;x<w;x++){
                for(y=0;y<h;y++){
                    float rc = cvGetReal2D(source, y, x);
                    float normRealColor =(rc - fminVal) / dif;
                    file << normRealColor << " ";
                }
                file << endl;
            }file << endl;
```

all my images are 8*8 size B&W but it returns to me something like:

```
-1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND 
-1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND 
-1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND 
-1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND 
-1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND 
-1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND 
-1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND 
-1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND
```

and returns it not always!!! from time to time I get desired stuff like

```
0 0 0 0.166667 0.166667 0.333333 0.333333 0.333333 
0.166667 0.166667 0.166667 0.333333 0.333333 0.5 0.5 0.5 
0.333333 0.333333 0.5 0.5 0.666667 0.666667 0.666667 0.833333 
0.5 0.5 0.666667 0.666667 0.833333 0.833333 0.833333 1 
0.666667 0.666667 0.666667 0.833333 0.833333 1 1 1 
0.5 0.666667 0.666667 0.666667 0.833333 0.833333 1 1 
0.5 0.5 0.5 0.666667 0.666667 0.833333 0.833333 0.833333 
0.333333 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.666667 0.666667 0.833333 0.833333
```

Any ideas?

BTW (I know there is cvNormalize(source,source,1,0,CV_MINMAX );  but I need to use hand written code...)

Comment: You don't want to use cvGetReal2d in a tight loop. Since you use C++, why don't you use the `cv::Mat` interface and use one of the methods of http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/fast_element_access.html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the result of division by 0, which means that `diff` is 0, which means some of your images are "flat", so that `minVal == maxVal`.

Answer (score 4):

RealColor is a double.  values is an array of ints.  You are shoving everything into ints without regard for what you're losing.

minval/maxval are ints, but when you take the difference of them, you put it into a float.  This is not going to magically give you back your precision.  It's gone.

make minval, maxval, and values be doubles instead of ints.  And handle the div/0 case.  Try that and see if it's any better.

Answer (score 1):

diff is obliviously 0.0, which means either

min_element(values,(values+wh)); max_element(values,(values+wh)); doesn't do what you think it does

or your images are wrong (are you checking that valid images are being loaded?)

Answer (score 1):

If `dif` is `0.0` then you would end up with infinities like you have.